# Missing CycleRecoverable JAXB Java

Tags: java, jaxb

I am trying to use the `CycleRecoverable` interface to manage cyclic issues in my object model for bi-directional relationships.  Guides such as [this](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_cyclic_references_to_XML.html) and [this](http://www.javafreedom.org/?p=485), tell you to use `CycleRecoverable`, but I don't have it on my class path.  I'm confused as to what I actually need, and an explanation as to why I need it.  I am not using `Maven`, so I can't follow the second links advice, and even if I was using `Maven`, I don't understand why I need more packages in order to use JAXB which I thought was included in `SE6`.  What jar files do I actually need to include to use this interface and why?  The only CycleRecoverable on my classpath is `com.sun.xml.internal.bind.CycleRecoverable`

The [(un)official JAXB guide](http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_cyclic_references_to_XML.html#Use_the_CycleRecoverable_interface) notates the interface, but makes no mention of how to actually use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the **[EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)** lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

As an alternative to the `CycleRecoverable` mechanism in the JAXB reference implementation you may be interested in the `@XmlInverseReference` extension in MOXy:

**Customer**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy="customer", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    private Address address;

}
```

**Address**

The `@XmlInverseReference` annotation specifies the field name that maps the other direction of this relationship.  This is similar to how bidirectional relationships are mapped in JPA.

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.*;

@Entity
public class Address implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private long id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ID")
    @MapsId
    @XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="address")
    private Customer customer;

}
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/jpa-entities-to-xml-bidirectional.html
- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html

Comment: Blaise, do you have a link of an example of how CycleRecoverable is normally handled on the unmarshaling side with stock JAXB versus how it is handled with MOXy?

Comment: @Ryan - The following thread (http://www.java.net/node/654639) contains a example of using `CycleRecoverable` with the JAXB-RI by gadams00 (I haven't tried it).